# Kotlin and realm: How to only insert nested RealmObjects when they do not exist?

Tags: kotlin, realm

I work with kotlin and the following dependencies:

```
id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.7.0"

implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
implementation("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.7.0")
```

General usecase:

I download multiple csv files, convert them to RealmObjects and then I try to save the list of RealmObjects. Of course, in this case it is possible that RealmObjects with the same PrimaryKey are saved multiple times: e.g. `QuantityRealmObject` is used in several RealmObjects within the parent (or root) object. I thought the UpdatePolicy.Modified which does not exist for Kotlin (?) would do exactly that.

As Jay described, `Upserting` is probably the way to go in this case, however I am not sure if

- I must implement this manually due to the lack of the `modified` policy:  Check for each `RealmObject` with a
  PrimaryKey within another `RealmObject` if it is already managed
  (`Realm.query()`), if yes use the managed object, else insert it
- Or if this can be achieved in an elegant, generic way
- Or if my whole approach is faulty and I should go about it in another way

I try to save data RealmDB which works but I do have nested RealmObjects with @PrimaryKeys. Currently my code only works with setting the UpdatePolicy to ALL which probably leads to a lot of unnecessary updates (and possibly a bigger filesize?) but less actual data in the db than when working with EmbeddedRealmObjects.

EDIT:

My problem is that my `Example` objects have references to other RealmObjects with PrimaryKeys (e.g. `QuantityRealmObject`) or references to other RealmObjects which have also references to `QuantityRealmObjects`. With UpdatePolicy.ALL if have the luxury that I can just call copyToRealm(exampleObject) and all references are saved correctly. If there is a duplicate primary key for a "nested" quantity object reference, it just updates it with the same values, but the references are still ok. If I want to upsert like you suggest, which of course works, I would have to check lots of "nested" realm object references for each copyToRealm(exampleObject) call:

```
val exampleObject

//query if exampleObject.field1.quantityRealmObject already exists, if not create it, if yes set this field to the already managed instance
//query if exampleObject.quantityRealmObject already exists, if not create it, if yes set this field to the already managed instance
//query if exampleObject.field2.field3.quantityRealmObject already exists, if not create it, if yes set this field to the already managed instance

// ... do that for lots of references

realm.copyToRealm(exampleObject)

//vs. 

realm.copyToRealm(exampleObject, UpdatePolicy.ALL)
```

I like the idea with error handling, however I am not sure how I could set the correct references in the ExampleObject in an error case.

```
fun createRealm(dbName: String, data: List<DataRealmObject>, schema: String) {
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(setOf(
            // a few RealmObject classes
        )
            .compactOnLaunch()
            .build()

        val realm = Realm.open(config)

        realm.writeBlocking {
            
            data.forEach {
                this.copyToRealm(it, UpdatePolicy.ALL)
            }    
   
        }


        realm.close()
    }
```

When I do not set the UpdatePolicy to ALL, of course I get exceptions stating that an object with the PrimaryKey already exists. Is there a good solution to deal with this without setting the UpdatePolicy to ALL? Ideal would be something like: if an object with the given PrimaryKey does not exist, insert it, else use the already existing object.

I do suspect that the massive updates on already existing objects has a negative effect on the filesize of the realmDb.

How could I solve this problem? I could query before each copy call if each nested RealmObject already exists, however this would be very complex since there are some basic types which occur in a lot of different fields.

EDIT:

An example object could look like this:

```
Example(): RealmObject{ 
    var field1: String = ""
    var anotherRealmObjectRef: Quantity? = null 
    var anotherRealmObjectRef2: Another? = null
    // other fields who can contain references to objects with PrimaryKeys
    
}

Quantity(): RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    var id = ""
    var value: Double = 0.0
    var unit: String = "" 
    
    // constructor sets id to e.g. value_unit 
}

Another(): RealmObject {
    // other fields
    var price: Quantity? = null
}
```

So as I said, I download csv files with data, convert each row to, in this case, `Example` realm objects. For each of those objects I must create also `Quantity` objects in multiple fields. I added an id field as PrimaryKey to  `Quantity` because in reality I create maybe 1 mio example objects but there will be only 10k unique `Quantity` objects. So I only want unique `Quantity` instances in my realmdb to save space and keep the filesize small. I could potentially check before I create each `Quantity` object, if there is currently another `Example` object which contains already `Quantity` objects with this PrimaryKey like you showed in your code example. Due to the somewhat complex class structure this would result in a lot of code and I am not sure if that is really feasible or good to do.

`UpdatePolicy.ALL` basically solves this for me, because the resulting realm db only consists of unique quantity objects. However it does probably a lot of unnecessary updates on those objects.

The only real problem for me currently is that the resulting realm db has an unexpected filesize (currently around 400-500mb). A comparable realm db created with the swift sdk has around 200mb. If this is due to the mass updates (resulting in a lot of object versions?) it would be worth for me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions within the question so let me try to tackle them all. I prefer including code in answers but perhaps some clarity about how Realm works would be more beneficial. Some of this answer is IMO so evaluate accordingly.

TL;DR - skip to the Edit

The code in the question doesn't work as is because it's trying to brute force add an object, which had a duplicate primary key to an existing object; primary keys must be unique so having two objects with the same primary key would not be allowed.

The difference between .all and .modified are related to how the data is written (keep reading: Upsert, which may be an answer).

`.all` forces all properties of an object to be re-written, whether they have changed or not. That's a whole lot of data to push around and I would find use cases for this kinda rare.

`.modified` only writes out fields that have been modified so in general, it's far less data and the preferred option. It will also allow for `Upsert` which is what you're attempting to do.

`.error`; if you want to prevent updating an existing object, error will throw an error if an object that the same primary key already exists

`Upsert`'ing is the process where if an object exists, it will be updated. If it does not exist, it will be inserted. To cause this behavior, when an object is being manipulated, set the update flag to `.modified` and it will magically be inserted if needed, otherwise just the modified fields will be updated on the existing object. Note that you can also partially update an object by passing the primary key and a subset of the values to update.

---

The question mentions "nested objects" and that's a bit ambiguous (IMO) when is comes to Realm. Unfortunately the documentation kinda of mixes 'nested' in so that can lead to confusion.

Nested: In a tree sits a birds nest with eggs. The eggs are nested; they are part of the nest and exist within and as part of the nest; they do not exist in other nests, only that nest.

Objects that are managed (and have a primary key) and are added to another object are not really "nested" - they do not become part of the parent object as they are stored by reference. The two objects are both managed and independent of each other, can exist without the other and in the case of a referenced object, can be referenced from multiple other objects (so, not really nested)

Embedded objects on the other hand are more akin to a 'nested' object; they are not managed separately, do not/can not contain a primary key and are part of the parent object's graph.

To update an embedded (nested) object would be done through dot notation starting with the parent `parentObject.embeddedChildToUpdate.fieldToUpdate` and would not be done using .modified or .all (in this context) since the field is being written directly. (and embedded objects would not ever be upserted since they cannot existing without the parent)

It doesn't appear you're using embedded objects - everything seems to be by reference so a bit OT but I hope that helps.

Edit

If the goal is to persist objects that have a unique primary key and to ignore those that are duplicates, this should do it. Attempt to read an object with a given primery key, if it does not exist, persist a new object; if it does exist, ignore it and move on to the next one.

```
for (widget in widgetList.find()) {
   realm.write {
      val widget = //fetch the widget via it's primary key

      //if there is no widget with that primary key, persist it
      if (widget == null) {
         widget.copyToRealm(WidgetClass().apply {
            _id = ObjectId()
            //populate the properties if needed
         }
      })

      //if we get here, a widget with that primary key exists
      //  so don't persist it (e.g. ignore it)
   }
}
```

This process does not need .all or .modified or even an upsert

The other option is to attempt to write each object - if an object with an existing primary key exists, and error will be thrown. Handle the error elegantly (pretty much do nothing) and then move on to the next object.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an elaborate answer Just to clarify, the code does work as is, however using UpdatePolicy.ALL is probably very (very) bad. I understand that realm keeps versions of RealmObjects, so does this have an impact on file size? I guess it really depends on the structure and number of objects (in my case around 1 mio.).  I also saw that a `modified` UpdatePolicy exists for the Swift implementation and I thought this is exactly what I need. However, kotlin offers "just" `all` and `error`? I am still not sure if my whole approach is faulty.

Comment: I updated the question with more information, so maybe this helps

Comment: I updated the answer with some code; but the update to the question you made needs some clarity so I don't send you the wrong direction. The question states *in this case it is possible that RealmObjects with the same PrimaryKey are saved multiple times* - the issue is PrimaryKeys are unique so there should never be objects with the same primary key. It's not clear why that's happening. Is it possible the objects are referencing another object? e.g. it's not actually a primary key but a reference to another objects primary key?

Comment: I added some more information. I saw the upserting as you described it in the documentation. However I am not sure if this is feasible for my complex class structure. I would have to query the realm db for each "nested" (sorry :)) RealmObject (which has a primary key field) reference which are a lot. Hope this makes my use-case a bit clearer.

Comment: @Christian I am still not real clear on the issue. Let me restate the use case; the goal is to read 1 Million CSV objects, populate Example Objects (per your question) and then store them in Realm, ignoring objects that have duplicate primary keys as those are not needed. I tweaked the pseudo-code in my answer but that should do it. The other option is basic error trapping; attempting to write an object with a primary key that already exists throws an error. See [Error handling](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/errors/) - if there's an error, handle it and move on.

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore the objects with the duplicate primary keys, but the current exampleObject instance should then reference the already managed, or persisted object. This would result imo in a lot of (complex) code when I have to check each nested reference of an exampleObject to other realm objects (with primary keys). I updated the question with some pseudo code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Christian I don't really follow this - *but the current exampleObject instance should then reference the already managed, or persisted object* - the result of that would be the current object ALSO being managed along with the prior object - therefore they would NOT be ignored and ALL of the objects would be managed, Right? e.g. if there's an existing, managed object, and another object is read in from the CSV and it's the same primary key, then when it's persisted, BOTH objects now exist. Meaning you're still storing all of the objects. Maybe re-thinking the objective and question would help?

Comment: I think I have trouble to explain that from each row in the csv file I create one "root" RootRealmObject a, and multiple other RealmObjects b, c, d (they have primary keys and are part of a through references). If I now call realm.copyToRealm(a) a, b, c and d are saved to the realm. The next row in the csv is now handled, RootRealmObject e is created along with other RealmObjects f, g, h which are part of e as references. f and g have primary keys which already exist. Now I call copyToRealm(e)

Comment: e and h are created, g and h throw an exception (constraint violation). I could solve this as you said before I save e, I check if f, g and h already exist in the realmdb, if they do I set the references to the already managed objects. Thats possible, but really complex and a lot of code. If I just call copyToRealm(e, UpdatePolicy.ALL) e, f, g and h are saved, however since f and g  already exist, they are updated (with the same values) which results in a lot of update operations, but that is the only problem imo.

Comment: Since I do this whole thing once to create initial databases for mobile apps, this is not really a big problem (unless I miss something?). I was just a bit confused since the java sdk and the swift sdk offer other UpdatePolicies which would solve the unnecessary mass updates without any actual changes. For kotlin, as I understand it, I would need to check by myself for each RealmObject with a PrimaryKey before I save it, if it already exists. Does this help to better grasp my "problem"? If not, I should like you suggested, rethink the question a bit or better illustrate it with an example